# AS3 Error: Access of possibly undefined property STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant

I have a Flex AIR project that compiles and runs in Flex Builder 4.6. I'm trying to create an Ant script that will build the project. On these lines I get these errors:

```
        _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS, inputProgressListener);
        _process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onNativeProcessExit);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[mxmlc] MyClass.as(190): col: 44 Error: Access of possibly undefined property STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA through a reference with static type Class.
[mxmlc]             _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
[mxmlc]                                                     ^
[mxmlc] MyClass.as(191): col: 44 Error: Access of possibly undefined property STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS through a reference with static type Class.
[mxmlc]             _process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS, inputProgressListener);
```

From what I can tell, these are defined in frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc. I think I'm including that with the compiler.external-library-path element below.

The compile target of my build.xml ant script looks like this:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
  <mxmlc file="${MAIN_SOURCE_FILE}" output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.swf"
       services="${APP_ROOT}/services/flex/services-config.xml">
    <swf-version>13</swf-version>
    <locale>en_US</locale>
    <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>

    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
     <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
    <source-path path-element="${APP_ROOT}/../MyLib/src"/>
    <source-path path-element="${APP_ROOT}/src"/>
    <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
        <include name="libs/air" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>

    <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
                    <include name="libs" />
                    <include name="../bundles/{locale}" />
                </compiler.library-path>
    <compiler.library-path dir="${APP_ROOT}" append="true">
                    <include name="libs" />
                    <include name="libs/player" />
                </compiler.library-path> 
    <define name="CONFIG::debugging" value="false"/>
     <compiler.debug>false</compiler.debug>             
  </mxmlc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change the `<load-config>` to be one of these:

```
<load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml"/>
```

or

```
<load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/airmobile-config.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to air-config.xml fixed it!